# Simple bare metal code on Pi 3 doesn't work

Tags: gpio, pi-3, bare-metal

I'm trying to run this bare metal code to turn BCM16 on. The code is made into raw binary and config.txt contains the necessary kernel= attribute. I measured with multimeter; nothing happened. What could be wrong?

```
00008000 <_start>:
    8000:   e59f001c    ldr r0, [pc, #28]   ; 8024 <hang+0x4>
    8004:   e3a01007    mov r1, #7
    8008:   e1a01901    lsl r1, r1, #18
    800c:   e5801000    str r1, [r0]
    8010:   e59f0010    ldr r0, [pc, #16]   ; 8028 <hang+0x8>
    8014:   e3a01001    mov r1, #1
    8018:   e1a01801    lsl r1, r1, #16
    801c:   e5801000    str r1, [r0]

00008020 <hang>:
    8020:   eafffffe    b   8020 <hang>
    8024:   3f200004    svccc   0x00200004
    8028:   3f20001c    svccc   0x0020001c
```

Comment: Someone in the official forum has figured out a bug regarding e3a01007    mov r1, #7, which should be #1, in order to set it to output function. I'll test the fix tomorrow and come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copying my comment here.

> Someone in the official forum has figured out a bug regarding e3a01007 mov r1, #7, which should be #1, in order to set it to output function.

It was indeed the why it did not work.